# É possivel importar um arquivo XML com interesse em substituir o XAML?

Tags: mobile, xaml, xamarin.android, android-xml

Bom dia senhoras e senhores,

Seria possível trabalhar com arquivo XML (layout) feito no Android Studio para usar no visual studio no caso de desenvolvimento android com o xamarin. 
Gostaria de substituir o arquivo AXML que vem como padrão no visual studio pelo o arquivo XML que é gerado pelo Android Studio.

PS: Parece loucura mas existe um projeto da google que o desenvolvedor só cola o codigo XML ou escreve e vê tudo sendo feito ao lado por um smartphone sem a necessidade de usar emuladores, leve e  muito pratico.

http://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer/#/android/linear-layout-weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Não confunda XAML com AXML. AXML é um nome dado aos arquivos XML de layout do Android Studio no Visual Studio. Um arquivo AXML possui XML dentro dele. Um arquivo XAML é um arquivo de layout também, porém usado no Xamarin Forms e em outras aplicações da Microsoft, como por exemplo WPF.**

Se você está trabalhando com Xamarin.Android, ou seja, um projeto nativo em Android através do Xamarin, então sim, é possível, pois o layout do Android no Visual Studio é definido através de arquivos chamados AXML que nada mais são que arquivos XML.

Se você está utilizando Xamarin Forms, então não, não é possível, pois conforme falado anteriormente, Xamarin Forms utiliza XAML para definição dos layouts.

XAML e AXML são arquivos de layout completamente diferentes e são interpretados de formas diferentes pelo compilador.

Concluindo, você pode tranquilamente copiar um layout em XML do Android Studio e colar no layout Android AXML do Visual Studio. Apenas observe se ele possui alguma propriedade @string, @dimen, @style ou @color que referencie para algum outro arquivo XML criado dentro da pasta 'values' por exemplo.

Comment: Então se por exemplo, eu quiser desenvolver para Android e Windows Phone utilizando o xamarin (Visual studio) eu teria que criar fazer um layout para o android e WP  ?

Comment: Se você quiser fazer isso utilizando reaproveitamento de código, você irá usar Xamarin Forms, onde você cria o layout XAML apenas uma vez e ele cria o layout nativo nas outras plataformas automaticamente pra você. Agora caso queira fazer isso individualmente, utilizando a programação nativa do Xamarin, você terá que criar layouts individualmente para cada plataforma, seja ela Android, iOS ou UWP.

Comment: @user3671786 se sua pergunta foi respondida, por favor marque como resposta, obrigado.